# compare strings in python with a text file

Tags: python, string

i have a text file with following data:
deric,
robert,
mathew,

Now, i want the user to input a string and then compare that string with the text file..

```
 fo = open("d:\\ar.txt", "r")
 file_contents = fo.read()
 print('Enter your password.')
 typedPassword = input()
 for i in file_contents:
     if typedPassword == file_contents:
         print('Access granted')
     else:
         print('Access denied')
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. any thoughts?

Comment: if typedPassword in file_contents

Comment: this may help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21903842/how-do-i-compare-two-strings-in-python

Answer (score 3):

Try this:-

```
fo = open("poopy.txt", "r")
file_contents = fo.read()
print('Enter your password.')
typedPassword = input()
Flag = 0
for i in file_contents.split('\n'):
    if typedPassword == i:
        Flag = 1
if Flag == 1:
    print('Access Granted')
else:
    print('Access Denied')
```

Answer (score 0):

You were checking if the inputted password maches the whole file...
This checks each line

```
username = input("Input your username")
password = input("Input your password")
correct = None
with open("d:\\ar.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.split(",")
        if username == line[0] and password == line[1]:
            correct = True
if correct:
    print("") # placeholder
    #(logged in code)
```

for this to work your file should be of the fornat

username,password,

username,password,

username,password,